# Reinitialise only new appended FB button

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I have an "article" page where the selected article is displayed by default and another articles are ajax-appended to the bottom after clicking on "next" button.

Every article has its own *FB share button*.

I can reinitialise all the buttons by `FB.XFBML.parse();` command, but the existing buttons disappear for a short moment during reinitialisation.

Is there a way to reinitialise only last appended button or somehow to prevent visual disappearing of the buttons?

---

*(Btw. this issue does not apply to twitter button, which can be reinitialised by `twttr.widgets.load();` command)*

Comment: How about you just go read the documentation for that method ...?

Comment: That is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FB.XFBML.parse()` function takes a parameter with selected DOM element. Then it will only reinitialise share buttons that are present in the DOM element:

```
        var buttons = newblog.find('.share-buttons')[0];
        FB.XFBML.parse(buttons);
```